# eloquent javascript table drawing function - drawRow arguments

Tags: javascript, function

As others have mentioned this code comes from chapter 6 of eloquent javascript. I do not understand where the arguments to the function 'drawRow' are supplied from. If the outer function drawTable were some sort of method it would make sense that it could pass an array as well as the current index, but it's not. It's just an ordinary function so where does it grab 'row' and 'rowNum' from?

```
function drawTable(rows) {
  var heights = rowHeights(rows);
  var widths = colWidths(rows);

  function drawLine(blocks, lineNo) {
    return blocks.map(function(block) {
      return block[lineNo];
    }).join(" ");
  }

  function drawRow(row, rowNum) {
    var blocks = row.map(function(cell, colNum) {
      return cell.draw(widths[colNum], heights[rowNum]);
    });
    return blocks[0].map(function(_, lineNo) {
      return drawLine(blocks, lineNo);
    }).join("\n");
  }

  return rows.map(drawRow).join("\n");
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls the provided callback (`drawRow` in your case) with three arguments for each element of the array that it is iterating over:

- the element
- the index
- the whole array (which you are not making use of here)

You could optionally also set some object to become `this` inside of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the callback supplied to map has three parameters: currentValue, index, and array.  In this case, when `drawRow` is supplied to `rows.map`, row is the currentValue, and rowNum is the index.

Here's a simpler example:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function printArray(value, index) {
    console.log(index + ' ' + value);
}

arr.map(printArray);
// prints
// 0 a
// 1 b
// 2 c
```

Comment: Thank you both of you for your quick replies, but I guess what I am still confused about is how anything inside of drawRow knows what 'row' is. I understand that using the map method can pass the three parameters you both mentioned, but how is the map method applied to the array 'row' without row being supplied from anywhere?

Comment: @user3827668 drawRow knows what a 'row' is because the map function supplies it with those values.  The map function is expecting a callback with three parameters, in the right order.  You could have named them whatever you want, but the first will be the member of the array, the second the index, and the third a reference to the original array.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing something here, but as I understand it the outermost function drawTable takes the parameter 'rows'. rows is an array of arrays of cells. Any single element of rows is itself just a 'row' which is an array of cells. The map function inside of drawRow somehow knows which particular row to be operating on and this I don't understand. Sure, you could apply the map method to the variable 'rows' but not 'row'.

Comment: `map` iterates over the rows in order they are in the `rows` array.  As you can see, even `row` within the drawRows function has `map` called on it to render each cell.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the `map` method calls `drawRow` passing the appropriate values. To illustrate the mechanics behind this let's create another function, called `M_A_P`, from scratch that would also call `drawRow` with the appropriate values:

```
function M_A_P (theArray, callback) {
    var returnArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<theArray.length; i++) {

        var result = callback(theArray[i],i); // note this line

        returnArray.push(result);
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

The function `M_A_P` above calls a function we supply to it with two arguments, the value of one item from `theArray` (`theArray[i]`) and the index of the item (`i`).

Now, we can use `M_A_P` to process the rows:

```
M_A_P(rows, drawRow).join("\n");
```

Remember that the function `drawRow` will be passed in to `M_A_P` as the variable `callback` and the array `rows` will be passed in as the variable `theArray`. `M_A_P` then will call `drawRow` the way described above with two arguments.

The method `Array.map()` works similarly but implemented as a method of array objects instead of a function.

Comment: omg, I don't why but after reading your very thoughtful re-iteration of what other people were saying I realized that this entire time I was somehow missing the rows.map call at the bottom. Jesus, I am so sorry for wasting your time. On the other hand it was your comment that sparked this realization, so thank you.